# Query xml data stored in PeopleSoft Integration Broker tables

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

Is there a way to query (sql) the xml data stored in a BLOB column of Peoplesoft IB tables (like MIMEDATALONG column in PSAPMSGPUBDATA table) ?

I tried Oracle BLOB to varchar2 etc. but it looks like there is some kind of encryption is involved.